# Problem 7, section 13 in Munkres' Topology, 2nd edition: which topology contains which?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Consider the following topologies on $\mathbb{R}$:

- $ \mathscr{T}_1 = $ the standard topology.
- $ \mathscr{T}_2 = $ the topology of $\mathbb{R}_K$ with the collection of all open intervals $(a,b)$ and all sets of the form $(a,b) \setminus \{1, 1/2, 1/3, \ldots\}$ as  basis.
- $ \mathscr{T}_3 =$  the finite complement topology.
- $ \mathscr{T}_4 = $ the upper limit topology, having all sets $(a,b]$ as basis.
- $ \mathscr{T}_5 = $ the topology having all sets $(-\infty, a) = \{x | x< a \}$ as basis.

Then which of these topologies contains which (not to mention trivial self-inclusions of course)?

I think $\mathscr{T}_1$ contains $\mathscr{T}_3$ and $\mathscr{T}_5$, whereas $\mathscr{T}_1$ is itself contained in $\mathscr{T}_2$ and $\mathscr{T}_4$.

I also think that $\mathscr{T}_2$ and $\mathscr{T}_4$ are incomparable.

Am I right?

What is the relation between $\mathscr{T}_3$ and $\mathscr{T}_5$?

Which other inclusions are possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have correctly placed $\mathscr{T}_1$ with respect to the other four topologies. $\mathscr{T}_2$ actually is contained in $\mathscr{T}_4$. You already know that each open interval $(a,b)$ is in $\mathscr{T}_4$, so consider a set $U=(a,b)\setminus K$, where $K=\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$. Let $x\in U$. If $(a,x)\cap K=\varnothing$, then $(a,x]$ is a $\mathscr{T}_4$-nbhd of $x$ contained in $U$. If $(a,x)\cap K\ne\varnothing$, there is a smallest $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $\frac1n\in(a,x)\cap K$, and in that case $\left(\frac1n,x\right]$ is a $\mathscr{T}_4$-nbhd of $x$ contained in $U$. Thus, every $x\in U$ has a $\mathscr{T}_4$-nbhd contained in $U$, and there $U\in\mathscr{T}_4$.

$\mathscr{T}_3$ is the smallest possible $T_1$ topology on $\Bbb R$, so $\mathscr{T}_3$ is contained in every $T_1$ topology on $\Bbb R$, and in particular in $\mathscr{T}_1,\mathscr{T}_2$, and $\mathscr{T}_4$. Moreover, every topology on $\Bbb R$ that contains $\mathscr{T}_3$ is a $T_1$ topology. Thus, $\mathscr{T}_3\nsubseteq\mathscr{T}_5$. But the only member of $\mathscr{T}_5$ with a finite complement is $\Bbb R$, so $\mathscr{T}_5\nsubseteq\mathscr{T}_3$: the two topologies are incomparable.

Clearly $\mathscr{T}_5\subseteq\mathscr{T}_1$, and you already know that $\mathscr{T}_1\subseteq\mathscr{T}_2$ and $\mathscr{T}_1\subseteq\mathscr{T}_4$, so $\mathscr{T}_5\subseteq\mathscr{T}_2$ and $\mathscr{T}_5\subseteq\mathscr{T}_4$

Comment: can we show that $\mathscr{T}_3$ and $\mathscr{T}_5$ are incomparable directly (i.e. without using the notion of a $T_1$ topology)?

Comment: @Saaqib: Sure: $(-\infty,0)\in\mathscr{T}_5\setminus\mathscr{T}_3$, and $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}\in\mathscr{T}_3\setminus\mathscr{T}_5$. It’s just useful to know that a topology on a set $X$ is $T_1$ if and only if it contains the cofinite topology on $X$, and this seemed a good place to mention it, since it makes part of the problem very easy.

Comment: M Scott so nice of you! How much I've learnt from you through the Maths StackExchange website!

Comment: @Saaqib: You’re very welcome! I’m always happy to help people learn.

Comment: @Btian M. Scott could you please also correct the allignment in my original post? I'm not sure the way I've written down the topologies is the best possible way.

Answer (score 2):

For reference:

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{matrix}
 & \tau_1       & \tau_2 & \tau_3 & \tau_4 & \tau_5\\ 
\tau_1 & =       & \supset & \subset & \supset & \subset\\ 
\tau_2 & \subset & = & \subset & \supset & \subset\\ 
\tau_3 & \supset & \supset & = & \supset & X\\ 
\tau_4 & \subset & \subset & \subset & = & \subset\\ 
\tau_5 & \supset & \supset & X & \supset & =
\end{matrix}
  \end{equation*}

The j-th collumn is contained($\subset$) / contains($\supset$) / is equal($=$) /is incomparable($X$) with the i-th row where all set inclusions are proper.